# Can't run my turtle Python3 files

Tags: laptop, python, linux-mint

I have just started programming in Python 3. I made a Snake Game from YouTube using the Turtle module. When I finally finished the coding, I ran it. It was OK, and I wanted to make it executable in Linux. So I was guided from a YouTube video again and it didn't work. I turned off the computer. When I opened it the next day and tried to open the same `.py` file from terminal, I got an error.

> AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'

[image]

I am using Atom text editor. When I tried to open the same file from the default text editor that Linux Mint comes with, it worked. I thought it was an Atom error I decided to write the code in Atom and copy/paste it to the Linux text editor. It worked a couple of times, but eventually it kept showing me the same error.

It's very weird because it worked very well at first without showing me any errors. I don't know if I changed anything, but that video that showed me how to make it executable changed something. I'm sure!

Here is the video that I watched: [Convert PY to EXE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIJIk_maO4&t=107s).

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you named it `turtle.py`. Rename it and all will be OK.

---

*The explanation:*

The command

```
import turtle
```

in your code **doesn't import the `turtle` module from the standard library**, but your own module (source file) `turtle.py`.

But — I'm sure — you did't define your own class `Turtle` in it, so the name `turtle.Turtle` is not defined.